# Tinymce automatically convert alphabet list to numeric list

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-plugins

I am using tinymce editor.I am having issue when I copy alphabet list from word document to tinymce editor it automatically convert alphabet list to numeric list please suggest any solution. Thanks

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1e8bab3946bcf9f82b5459b77a7af49e

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `init` has something in it that's removing `type="a"` from your pasted list, reverting it to the default numeric style for ordered lists.